# SQL Server - With Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a query containing a WITH clause.  Like so:

```
WITH Temp (PIN)
AS
(
    SELECT t1.FIELD_VAL FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.primKey = '9549' AND t1.field2 = 10
)

SELECT wfu.SS_PEID, wfu2.IFAS_USERID
FROM Temp temp
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON temp.PIN = t2.PIN
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3b t3b ON t3.ID = t3b.ID
WHERE t3.ASStID IS NOT NULL OR wfu.ASSTID != ''
```

In the SELECT statement in the WITH clause above, I have the t1.primKey hard coded to '9549'.  When I change that to use the parameter passed in @Var like so:

```
WITH Temp (PIN)
AS
(
    SELECT t1.FIELD_VAL FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.primKey = @Var AND t1.field2 = 10
)

SELECT wfu.SS_PEID, wfu2.IFAS_USERID
FROM Temp temp
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON temp.PIN = t2.PIN
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3b t3b ON t3.ID = t3b.ID
WHERE t3.ASStID IS NOT NULL OR wfu.ASSTID != ''
```

it no longer works.  Why wouldn't that SELECT statement in the WITH clause work with a parameter variable in it?

...

Edit:

:) My apologies.  In my head it seemed understood what was not happening.  So with the value hard coded t1.primKey = '9549' I get results from the query.  When I change it to use the parameter of the stored procedure, t1.primKey = @Var no results are returned.

As far as setting the value of the parameter, in the stored procedure it is simply the parameter that is passed in from the application or when I execute the procedure from SSMS.  I have tested this in a new query window with the following declare and set statement:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR;
SET @Var = '9549';
```

Comment: (1) How does it not work?  (2) Parameters work with `with` as well as with the rest of the query.  I have lots of code that does this.

Comment: Can you give us the error message? Or, tell us how the result is different from what you expected?

Comment: How do you declare and set the variable `@var`?

Comment: `WITH` is used to define CTE - Common Table Expression, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @MaciejLos - what has that got to do with anything?  I don't think iJared ever questioned what `WITH` was

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, It's semantic matter: `WITH` clause does not exists, but `WITH` statement exists ;)

Comment: Put a semi-colon before the `with` (or after the last statement before it).

Comment: So why would anyone down vote this without any comment or suggestions as to why this SPROC doesn't work.  I've worked with SQL Server for many years and know that this should work.  It's a simple query yet I don't get why I don't get any results from the query when I have the parameter variable versus hard coding the value for testing.  @MaciejLos I wasn't going to technical definitions or phrases.  Everyone understood what I was referring too whether I called it a clause, phrase, expression, or the like.  In English those terms as synonymous.

Comment: @iJared, i don't know why someone downvoted your question. I know that  words used by you are synonymous. Please, read Laurence's comment...

Comment: @MaciejLos I did read his comment but I saw your response to his comment and just added my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this same question on MSDN here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0705dcd8-d05d-4fa6-b2d0-01570cd40186/sql-server-with-expression?forum=transactsql

It's odd I had never run into this scenario before and had always set the length of my VARCHAR parameters or used NVARCHAR.  So with the parameter as @Var VARCHAR or as in the code above DECLARE @Var VARCHAR the default length is 1.  So when I set the variable to '9549' I was only getting '9'.  I thought leaving it open meant the length would be determined when the value was passed in.

Hope this helps someone else someday :p.

Comment: First, that was a nice find.  Second, just for future reference, I think an answer may have been found sooner with the full DDL of your SPROC, so if you're having a problem, err on the side of providing too much of your code instead of too little.